# Access to properties from created bean

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans

I have that class as you can see below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:sample.properties")
public class SampleConfig {
 @Value("${attr1.prop}")
 private String attr1;

 @Value("${attr2.prop}")
 private String attr2;
 @Bean
 public SampleService sampleService() {
  return new SampleService(attr1);
 }

 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
}
```

I created SampleService bean with parameter attr1. Is possible get access to that properties which I load with @PropertySource later? For example after @Autowired.

Here is code of of using that bean:

```
@Service
public class SuperHotServiceImpl {

   @Autowired
   SampleService sammpleService;

   public void fooFunc() {
      // here I need some magic to get value of attr2.prop
      sammpleService.setAttr(attr2);
   }
}
```

Can you tell if it is possible an how? Thanks

Comment: What exactly holds you from simply having a `@Value("${attr2.prop}") String attr2` field inside the service?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino email for notfycation, which I need to change in runtime in fooFunction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly your question, then this should help:

```
@Service
public class SuperHotServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private SampleConfig sammpleConfig;

    public void fooFunc() {
        System.out.println(sampleConfig.getAttr2());
    }
}
```

Supposed that `SampleConfig` is annotated as `@Component` and that you provide the getter.

Comment: is sampleConfig.attr2 possible when attr2 is private?

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about it, but I wasn't sure if is it a good practice.

Comment: And why not? It is not bad practice splitting configuration data and their usage. But still you may AS WELL AS put the `@Value("${attr2.prop}") String attr2` field inside the service, as @CoderinoJavarino suggested.